# Swiper hash navigation not showing hash slide, always shows first slide

Tags: sveltekit, swiper.js

## SOLVED (ugly hack)

idk if I should even called it solved as I'm just manually fixing the issue;

```
    $: currentCategory = $page.url.hash;
    $: {
        if (swiperRef && currentCategory) {
            const index = categories.findIndex(
                (category) => category.hash === currentCategory.replace('#', '')
            );
            if (index !== -1 && swiperRef.swiper.activeIndex !== index) {
                swiperRef.swiper.slideTo(index, 1, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I'm using swiper elements in a sveltekit project. I'm trying to get hash navigation to work.

The hash updates when clicking through the pagination, but when trying to load a certain slide directly by its hash it still always displays the first slide.

```
...
    import { Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
...

    <swiper-container
        slides-per-view={1}
        pagination={{
            clickable: true
        }}
        class="checklist-swiper w-full"
        hashNavigation={{
            enabled: true,
            watchState: true
        }}
    >
        {#each categories as category}
            <swiper-slide class="flex flex-col items-center" data-hash={category.hash}>
                                <p> blabla </p>
            </swiper-slide>
        {/each}
    </swiper-container>
```

I've tried with and without importing modules, I've tried different cases (hashNavigation doesn't work with kebab case, then I don't see the change in the URL), I've tried getting the reference and doing slideTo the hash in onMount, but I don't seem to have access to the hash there...

Thoughts?